# DisplayToast messages not appearing for Android 6.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working in Xamarin Android platform.
I used a simple DisplaYToast message

> DisplayToast("Error", ToastType.Error);

But this message does not appear in Android 6.0.
It works in Android 7.0 nougat on all devices.

Has anyone faced this issue??

Comment: What is `DisplayToast`? A custom method? Third-party code?

Answer (score 0):

use this to display toast messages in xamarin android.

```
Toast.MakeText(this,"Error",ToastLength.Short).Show();
```